# Sun Grid Engine (SGE) / limiting simultaneous array job sub-tasks

Tags: scheduler, gridengine

I am installing a [Sun Grid Engine](http://gridengine.sunsource.net) environment and I have a scheduler limit that I can't quite figure out how to implement.

My users will create [array jobs](http://wikis.sun.com/display/gridengine62u3/Submitting+Array+Jobs) that have hundreds of sub-tasks.  I would like to be able to limit those jobs to only running a set number of tasks at the same time, independent of other jobs.  Like I might have one array job that I want to run 20 tasks at a time, and another I want to run 50 tasks at a time, and yet another that I'm fine running without limit.  It seems like this ought to be doable, but I can't figure it out.

There's a [`max_aj_instances` configuration option](http://gridengine.sunsource.net/nonav/source/browse/~checkout~/gridengine/doc/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_conf.html?pathrev=V62u3_TAG), but that appears to apply globally to all array jobs.

I can't see any way to use [consumable resources](http://wikis.sun.com/display/gridengine62u3/Defining+Consumable+Resources), as I'd need a "complex attribute" that is per-job, and that feature doesn't seem to exist.

It didn't look like [resource quotas](http://gridengine.sunsource.net/nonav/source/browse/~checkout~/gridengine/doc/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_resource_quota.html?pathrev=V62u3_TAG) would work, but now I'm not so sure of that.  It says "A resource quota set defines a maximum resource quota for  a particular  job  request", but it's unclear if an array job's sub-tasks' resource requests will be aggregated for the purposes of the resource quota.  I'm going to play with this, but hopefully someone already knows outright.